# push notifications with ratchet webscoket

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, ratchet

I'm working with codeigniter, and ratchet websocket, I have set up codeigniter with ratchet well, but im having problems with logic, I have to do  in codeigniter and ratchet, I want to send notifications to a specif user in my model , addNotification, checkForNotifications, getNotifications , ,removeUserNotifications, removeNotifications

```
if ($arr = getNotifications() > 0){
     //Mostrar en tabla $arr
     if $arr[0].type == UNREAD
         //mostar un icono adecuado para unread
     else if $arr[0].type == NEW
                 //mostar un icono adecuado para new
   else if $arr[0].type == VIEWED
                 //mostar un icono adecuado para viewd

}else{
   echo "No tienes notifications"
}
```

then send them

how can I do it?

```
public function websocket(){
        $entryData = array(
            'category' => $_POST['category'], 
            'title'    => $_POST['title'], 
            'article'  => $_POST['article'], 
            'when'     => time()
         );

        $context = new ZMQContext();
        $socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'my pusher');
        $socket->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");
        $socket->send(json_encode($entryData));
    }
```

i need someone could help how can I do it dinamically without touch views, just controller and model because the own system will do it